# Automatic "entry" column in LaTeX tables

Tags: latex

I was wondering if it is possible with LaTeX to create a table with multiple rows and columns and have an automatic "entry" column in every table? This means I would like the first column of every table saying "entry" and numbering the rows of the column from 1 to n. (I hope that kind of explains what I want to achieve).

I will need to refer to single entries in a column and it would be easier to have that numbering done automatically in case I change the order of the rows later on.

Is there any way to do that or a package to make that work?

I am new to the whole LaTeX thing so please be easy on the technical terms :)

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is for questions related to programming and software development. For LaTeX questions there’s http://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this TeXBlog post](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/latex-general/table-row-count/).

You want to create a counter using `\newcounter`, set it to zero using `\setcounter`, then at the beginning of each row, increment the counter and print out its value. The example I linked to makes use of a nifty feature of the `tabular` environment where, in specifying the format for a column, you can also specify a piece of code to be included before each cell in that column. This saves you from having to duplicate the code, as is done in [this example](http://www.oconnoat.com/blog/2009/03/10/automatic-table-row-numbers-in-latex/).